# How to handle multiple data requests to an http resource in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have about 15 fruits, that has to hit a url:

```
http://myurl/fruit1
http://myurl/fruit2
http://myurl/fruit3
...
http://myurl/fruit15
```

It can occur asynchronously, what is the best way to get all 15 without tanking the server? Each item should be added to a list as they are retrieved.

Note that this happens every time a user visits the page. The fruit data does not change. Its going out to fetch the data, and add to list. My concern is the fact that it has to make multiple requests, which I want to not affect the performance of the application/browser (i.e. freezing for moments while its waiting for an HTTp request to return as information for each fruit is about 1.5MB.

Comment: If your list of fruit is static, why load one at a time? Just return the list in one call and be done with it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am worried because of the file size of each "fruit" response is 1.5MB, I need to split it up into multiple calls. If the user were to request for 5000 fruit onload, I can't have a single resource that returns all 5000, I think requesting one at a time to populate the list makes more sense so there is no need for user to wait until all 5000 fruits are loaded. I am open to any recommendations.

Comment: Pushing 30 MB to a user for a single page seems quite excessive. Supposing doing so is absolutely necessary and you want your page to be somewhat responsive during the initial load, then async is the way to go. Otherwise, a synchronous load with a pretty picture indicating as much will probably be your best user experience. Caching will be the only thing that would save you after the initial load though. Finally, freezing on an async request seems like you may have a rendering issue with your content that will have to be tackled as well.

Answer (score 0):

How frequently does the fruit data change?

If frequency of data change is low, then caching should solve a lot of problems outside of the initial retrieval of the data. If the frequency is high consider requesting a range or list of fruit from the server instead of individually. This will reduce a large amount of transfer overhead (1 request vs 15 requests).

Comment: Its not about reducing the number of requests, but I want to know what is the best way to handle calling multiple single requests.

Comment: It remains that if you want to transmit 1.5MB of data that you should be splitting it up into chunks. Consider implementing the ability to request ranges. Then you can pull the fruit 1000 records at a time so the response time is much faster. Again, caching is worth looking into for a decrease in load time as well.